# Using punctuation with abbreviations (eg. comma after a state abbrev.)

Tags: punctuation

231 N. Irby Street
Florence, S.C., 29501

Is this correct?
I just received a box of checks back and the comma looks wrong after S.C.,

Comment: Isn't the standard method for abbreviating states to not use periods? e.g. SC as opposed to S.C.? Also, there should be a comma after 'street'.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? An explanation would help!

Answer (score 1):

The post office has standards that have come into general use in writing. So unlike the way I was taught in the 70's, (longer abbreviation for the state and then comma) I now would write

...nce SC 29501

With the modern 2-letter code and no commas.
That is, the same as the [USPS guidelines](http://pe.usps.com/businessmail101/addressing/deliveryAddress.htm) for use on an envelope.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what style you adhere to. It is **correct** as per the [AP style manual](http://writingexplained.org/ap-style/ap-style-state-abbreviations).

Comment: The site you linked states that "Postal Code abbreviations should only be used with _full addresses, including a zip code._" Since the question poses a full address with zip code, the form with periods is incorrect.